# Angular - mat selection list passing value

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i have this code in mat selection list.

```
<mat-selection-list #profilesList [(ngModel)]="selectedProfiles" [multiple]="false" class="list">
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let profile of observables.profiles; last as last" [value]="profile"
     [selected]="profile.isCurrent">
      <div [ngClass]="{'list-item': true, 'selected': profile.isCurrent}">
         <label class="profileDesignation">{{profile.displayText}}</label>
       </div>
</mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

and i want to acess this Profile in another Button. i have a code for the button.

```
<button id="selectButton" class="bottomButton" type="button" (click)="selectProfileAndApply(profilesList.selectedOptions[0])"
        matTooltip="Profile go">
</button>
```

i have also a method in (click) inside this method i want to access the profileList in mat selection list.

but i cannot access it. any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to access to selected option in a wrong way. You can access selected option via `selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value` not `selectedOptions[0]`

Since you have also bind ngModel for selectedProfiles, you can also use it to access in typescript code as below:

```
selectProfileAndApply(profile: Profile): void {
  console.log(this.selectedProfiles); // You can use it as you bind this object to list via ngModel
  console.log(profile); // This is the value of selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value
}
```

I have created a [working stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a2n5td?file=src/app/list-single-selection-example.html)

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback but i tried with your suggestion. i got an error

"Cannot read property 'selectedOptions' of undefined"

Comment: Well, this seems strange... Could you please create a new Stackblitz to reproduce the problem and share here? You an use the one I created to tweak it and share later on.

Comment: @Laure I realized I shared the wrong url for stackblitz. You can now use it for editing.

Comment: @Laure I have edited my answer again to let you try to access elements in another way too :) Could you also check it?

Comment: i tried in stackblitz is working like i want but i try now in my environtment. thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Laure, Does it also work in your environment? If not, you can share the StackBlitz to reproduce the problem and share it.

Comment: Also, if my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as approved answer :)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion and now its working in my environtment in another way but the same ideas. i will mark your answer as approved answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
selectedProfiles
```

As i see you are using this property for binding values from mat-selection list.
You should use it for button

Comment: i tried with this selectedProfiles but still no action in it.